# Grep /var/log for hacker/script kiddy activity and e-mail?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, centos6, grep

CentOS 6
Apache Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

Thinking about how to automatically, once a day, grep all the logs in /var/log/httpd for hacker, phishing, etc activity and e-mail it to myself so I can evaluate what I might need to do.

But what are the patterns I can look for?

IE, we dont run Wordpress and we see a lot of attempts to access Wordpress related content, obviously for an exploit. Same with PHPMyAdmin.

I could do something like repeatedly, matching common patterns we see.

`# grep -r -i wp-content /var/log/httpd/`

`# grep -r -i php-my-admin /var/log/httpd/`

How do I e-mail myself this the results of each grep command or better yet all Grep results in a single e-mail?

Comment: http://www.ossec.net/doc/manual/monitoring/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mail the output of multiple commands like this:

```
{ grep -r -i wp-content /var/log/httpd/
  grep -r -i php-my-admin /var/log/httpd/
} | mailx -s SUBJECT admin@example.org
```

For what to grep is not so easy though. Rather than grep for particular attack patterns, I'd `grep -v` all known good lines and mail what's left.

Comment: Can you show me an example? I am a bit confused about using -v and the man page is confusing as well -v, --invert-match Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: `grep -v` shows everything *except* matching lines, i.e. `grep -v FOO` will remove all lines containing FOO from the output.

Comment: I got it, so I grep for all things that are normal. Can I `grep -v FOO BAR JASON 6Colors` in one large command?

Comment: You have to use `grep -v "FOO BAR JASON 6Colors"` if you want to exclude lines that contain the string "FOO BAR JASON 6Colors", or `grep -E -v "FOO|BAR|JASON|6Colors"` if you want to exclude lines that contain any of the words "FOO", "BAR", "JASON" or "6Colors".